# Initialise variable with ST_Polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I use ST_Polygon in my queries:

```
ST_Polygon('LINESTRING(-71.9436023 41.3108239,
            -71.7237582 41.0254994,
            -73.2015354 41.0545020,
            -71.9436023 41.3108239)'::geometry, 4326)
```

But I need to use the same polygon in a few places and would like to define variable for that. I found out that I can define a session variable. But pgAdmin 4 fails on the ST_Polygon definition:

```
SET my.ny_state = ST_Polygon('LINESTRING(-71.9436023 41.3108239,
        -71.7237582 41.0254994,
        -73.1465612 40.5889282,
        -71.9436023 41.3108239)'::geometry, 4326);
```

With `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ST_Polygon"`

How can I define and initialize variables using ST_Polygon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Customized options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-custom.html)* are not meant to be used as user variables, and I **strongly suggest** to not use this approach - and while it is possible to use them as a workaround, they come with limitations, i.e. they accept *string literals* only, and the `SET` command requires *constants* (in contrast to *function results*).

For reference, you could do:

```
SET my.ny_state = 'SRID=4236;POLYGON((-71.9436023 41.3108239, -71.7237582 41.0254994, -73.1465612 40.5889282, -71.9436023 41.3108239))';

SELECT current_setting('my.ny_state')::GEOMETRY(POLYGON, 4326);
```

---

You have several, more native options to imitate global constant state:

- copy & paste the values into the statements; simple, effective - but apparently not what you are looking for
- use inside a CTE for multiple usages within a sequence of statements:

  ```
  WITH
    const(id, geom) AS (
      VALUES (1, 'SRID=4236;POLYGON((-71.9436023 41.3108239, -71.7237582 41.0254994, -73.1465612 40.5889282, -71.9436023 41.3108239))'::GEOMETRY(POLYGON, 4326))
    ) ...
  ```
- use a surrogate *function*:

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ny_state_geom()
    RETURNS GEOMETRY(POLYGON, 4326) LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE AS
      $$ SELECT 'SRID=4236;POLYGON((-71.9436023 41.3108239, -71.7237582 41.0254994, -73.1465612 40.5889282, -71.9436023 41.3108239))'::GEOMETRY(POLYGON, 4326); $$
  ;


  SELECT ST_Area(ny_state_geom());
  ```
- use a constant *table* and retrieval functions:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE geom_constants (
    uid    INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" TEXT,
    geom   GEOMETRY(POLYGON, 4326)
  );

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON geom_constants ("name");

  INSERT INTO geom_constants ("name", geom)
    VALUES ( 'ny_state', 'SRID=4236;POLYGON((-71.9436023 41.3108239, -71.7237582 41.0254994, -73.1465612 40.5889282, -71.9436023 41.3108239))'::GEOMETRY(POLYGON, 4326) )
  ;


  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION geom_constant (
    "name" TEXT
  ) RETURNS GEOMETRY(POLYGON, 4326) LANGUAGE SQL AS
      $$ SELECT geom FROM geom_constants WHERE "name" = $1; $$
  ;

  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION geom_constant (
    uid INT
  ) RETURNS GEOMETRY(POLYGON, 4326) LANGUAGE SQL AS
      $$ SELECT geom FROM geom_constants WHERE uid = $1; $$
  ;


  SELECT ST_Area(geom_constant('ny_state'));
  SELECT ST_Area(geom_constant(1));
  ```

Comment: Thank you. The first suggestion is good enough for me to move on because it is just a short analysis of data that will not be used in the future. But I will definitely save your answer for my future use.